# What is flashover in PCB and the physics behind it

Tags: voltage, pcb, circuit-design, electromagnetism

I was learning about PCB trace to trace spacing.

For high voltage traces if the spacing is not proper, what I read is flashover will occur.

I searched on google about what is flashover and how it is happening.

Can anyone tell the physics behind flashover?

Comment: Search for "dielectric breakdown" and you will find plenty of information. The breakdown happens through the airgap, or through surface contaminants.

Comment: You can use also "trenching" (don't know if it is the good "word") between the high voltage area and the others. This is used in some "good" power supplies.

Comment: @Antonio51 The word I'd use for what you're talking about is "anti-tracking slots". "trenching" implies to me that it doesn't cut all the way through the board.